# Regex: extracting a house number from an address

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I have following patterns:

1. 13 R 2
2. 48 B / 5
3. 42 B
4. 42B
5. 303 Box 15
6. 303 Bte 15
7. 303 B Bt 15

and only want to have the following results (because Box 15, Bte 15 are the box numbers, and I only want the house nbr + potentially the letter attached to the house number):

1. 13 R 2
2. 48 B / 5
3. 42 B
4. 42B
5. 303
6. 303
7. 303 B

Is this possible using a regular expression? I tried the following: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_string_variable, '^\d+(\s*\w$)?')`. This however only works for the patterns 3-5, and not for the first 2 and last patterns. Dropping the `$` from the `regex` would incorrectly 'strip' the first letter for patterns 5 and 6.

I am basically assuming that if the letter behind the numeric is more than 1 character, that it belongs to the box number. For example, `BTE` is the French abbreviation for `Boite` which means `Box`. I realise this might be invalid if a house number has 2 letters (e.g.: 11 AA), but I would not know a solution for this and I don't think it occurs much.

Comment: Try `^\d+(\s*(/\s*)?([[:upper:]]|\d+))*(\s|$)`

Comment: You may use: [`^\d+.*?(?= Box | Bte? |$)`](https://regex101.com/r/jUWFIh/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove: *a space followed by an uppercase letter followed by at least one lowercase letter followed by an optional space followed by any number of digits*:

```
RegExp_Replace(house_number, '\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s+\d+$')
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jUWFIh/2)